# SQL database creation error while executing "ExecuteNonQuery" in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I want to Deploy C# application with SQL database. I am using database scripts in MSI insataller. My database scripts working fine on DBCC (database console command) of SQL server 2005 management studio. But while executing "ExecuteNonQuery" in installer it gives exception shown in screen shot.
[image]

How can I resolve it?
I am using following connection string.

```
                    connString = "Data Source = " + machineName + "\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = master; Integrated Security = SSPI";
```

Comment: Can you post the query that is being executed? Looks like the query is syntactically not correct.

Comment: This query working fine if I execute it on SQL server.

Comment: i hope people can help you better if you post your code & query along with this exception screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the 'GO' command inside of a SqlCommand like that.  Here's a good explanation and a few workarounds:

[http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/07/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-*2D00*-the-easy-way.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/07/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-_2D00_-the-easy-way.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Place semicolon (`;`) after each `GO` statement, or even better each statement. When using DML statements, SQL Server accepts them without semicolons, but when using `GO` you have to delimit them.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this;

http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/c-executing-batch-t-sql-scripts-with-go-statements/

Answer (score 0):

Replace go with new line (\r\n). That will run all the commands in the string var in sequence.